# How to aggregate layers into themes using ArcGIS Web AppBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

County of Simcoe have a nice interactive map based on ArcGIS Web AppBuilder, at https://maps.simcoe.ca/Public/

This application contains functionality I haven't seen before in a WAB map - it aggregates layers into "themes", allowing the user to change the contents of the map with a single click:

[image]

Is this function provided by an existing WAB widget, or is this something that Simcoe have written from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Simcoe via Twitter and they confirmed that they wrote custom functionality to handle this.